# Adding JavaScript JQuery to HTA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vbscript, hta

I'm currently building an HTA application that perfoms most functions through VBScript.

I have the need to include some JQuery that will allow customised tooltips. When I try to add 
`<script language="javascript" src="jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript">`
`</script>`
to my application underneath the VBScript, I'm unable to run the HTA. I recieve a "Microsoft JScript Runtime Error" with error "'jQuery' is undefined".

I've not even begun to add any references to the tooltips in the HTML - I can't even get past this stage.

[This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/37246a26-6401-4d3f-87c7-77046e11b8af/when-using-an-hta-on-ie9-the-getobject-function-is-undefined-when-specifying-xuacompatible-tag?forum=ITCG) technet page talks about using the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` tag, however that didn't appear to make any difference.

Am I doing something obviously wrong / not possible? I was under the impression different language types were supported under HTA's, as I have JavaScript included already to resize my HTA window.

Comment: does the jQuery file exist in the same folder as the HTA?

Comment: That looks like an addin that requires jQuery proper to also be included

Comment: You may need to use the meta/edge tag to bump up the compatibility mode as well

Comment: @WhiteHat The jQuery does exist in the same folder as the HTA.

Comment: @AlexK. I think I might have misunderstood how JQuery works, is there a binary / file that I need to place on my machine other than the .js file I'm referencing?

Comment: You need to include jQuery.js itself before the plugin http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>  works for me Im using Windows 7 IE 11 and Jquery 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alek K. mentioned, the plugin I was using had dependencies based on the base jQuery.js